# To have an alert box in browser set by express

Tags: javascript, express, nodemailer

I'm using express to send email by `nodemailer` module.
 my code is following:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
const output = `
<p>You have new one contact request</p>
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>
<li>Name:${req.body.name}</li>
<li>Email:${req.body.email}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p>
`;

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'mymail@gamil.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: '2020' // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

// send mail with defined transport object
let mailOptions = {
    from: "mymail@gamil.com", // sender address
    to: "myfriend@gmail.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "the subject", // Subject line
    html: output // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    // , info.res
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodeMailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
   res.render('index', { msg: 'email has been sent' });
    res.redirect('back');
});});
```

after clicking `submit` button, below code redirects to the Contact page:

```
        res.redirect('back');
```

and then shows a message by this code:

```
       res.render('index', { msg: 'email has been sent' });
```

now my aim is to instead of showing text by the forementioned code, showing the text in an alert box.
what I've tried for is like:

```
res.render('index','<script>alert("email has been sent")</script>');
```

but this doesn't work at all. by the way I'm not using `ajax`. then any idea or solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Running a script directly from a server response like `<script>doSomethingMaybeBad();</script>` will not likely run in modern browsers as it could be used as an attack. At a glance anyway it doesn't seem like you're loading the full page `<html>...</html>` on the client side with these requests.

I recommend listening to ajax responses from the client side and showing an alert then. Without seeing all your code, here's a rough idea:

Replace:

```
res.render('index','<script>alert("email has been sent")</script>');
```

with a JSON response, or response in the same format as you had it before like this:

```
{ msg: 'email has been sent', status: 200 }
```

Then in your client code, replace something like this (just guessing what you have as you didn't post a client side example):

```
$('msg').html(response.msg)
```

With:

```
if (response.status === 200) {
    alert(msg.msg);
    // consider redirecting here if needed?
} else {
    // show error, jQuery in this example however may be different for your current
    $('msg').html(response.msg)
}
```